# What is a reliable way to backup my virtual machine data?

Tags: virtual-machine, backup, vmware

I do a lot of tech work, mostly in Linux, but since I also like to play a few PC games, I run a powerful desktop PC which uses Windows as the host OS, but I run a few linux VMs to do all of my work using the paid version of VMWare Workstation. Before I started working in VMs, backups were as simple as just backing up the files on my host system using Windows backup tools but with the VMs, I'm a bit puzzled on the most effective way to back up my work data. I've thought of a few ideas:

1. Inside the VMs, run a tool like Spider Oak backup which will just backup all of the files from within the VM as if it were a standard bare-metal machine.
2. Run this or a similar tool on the **host machine**, and it will back up all of my game data in addition to the large VM files and hopefully if something bad happened, I could get the VM files out and then open them in VMWare again on a different system.
3. Use the Windows native file backup tools on the host similar to #2.

Of course, another option would be to manually try to either backup all files in each VM to an external drive, or copy the VM files out from the host to a drive on a regular basis.

However, I'm not really sure what option is best for me, or if they are even proper ways to do this. There are 2 things I should note about what I'm trying to do:

1. I tend to forget to run backups myself, so I'd prefer if they were automatically run quite frequently, which is why I was thinking of using a service like Spider Oak. But I'm concerned that if e.g. it were to backup a VM state or drive file, that it could catch it at a bad time and wind up with a corrupt or incomplete copy of the VM data, since the VMs are basically always running.
2. The main goal is that if my host drive(s) fail, I can get my VM files off the drive(s) and not lose data from my work VMs.

Finally, I should also state that I'm aware services such as AWS and Azure allow customers to backup images on a regular basis, so they must have figured out a good way to do this. I've seen a few other similar questions, but they seem to be for macOS and/or Virtualbox instead of my setup.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be using a backup utility like handy backup to make copies of the vdi/vhd drives themselves is your best option. Not only with this preserve your data, but you can set it up to do  versioned backups. This would create multiple backups so if your most recent backup is corrupt you can restore from a backup the day before or the day before that. You can also use scheduling to run the backup at a specific time which means you don’t have to manually run it. The nice thing about handy backup is you can choose where to store your backups too. Whether it be to an external drive, an installed recovery drive, and even options to upload to clouds like Dropbox or google drive.